# Use OneToOneField inlined in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have *DataFile* models which have *LogOutput* objects. A *DataFile* object will have a single *LogOutput*. For any *LogOutput* that belongs to a *DataFile*, it will only belong to a single *DataFile*. Other models also have *LogOutput* objects.

Since they are one-to-one, except that *LogOutputs* can belong to things other than *DataFiles* (eg. *Suites* have them too -- see code below) I thought the right thing to do would be to have a OneToOneField defined in *DataFile* that is the *LogOutput*.

**models.py**:

```
class LogOutput(models.Model):
    raw = models.TextField()

class DataFile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()#etc.
    logoutput = models.OneToOneField(LogOutput)

class Suite(models.Model):
    # Many Suites will have the same datafile:
    datafile = models.ForeignKey(DataFile)

    # Each Suite has a unique LogOutput different from the DataFile's
    # and as with the DataFile, that LogOutput will have just one Suite
    logoutput = models.OneToOneField(LogOutput)
```

Now, when I look at a DataFile in the Admin view, I want to see the LogOutput, so I thought I would just inline it.

**admin.py**:

```
class LogOutputInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = LogOutput

class DataFileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['name']
    inlines = [LogOutputInline]

admin.site.register(DataFile, DataFileAdmin)
```

It appears that because of the directionality of where the OneToOneField(s) are defined, I can't do the inlining. The above admin.py gives me:

```
<class 'trial.models.LogOutput'> has no ForeignKey to <class 'trial.models.DataFile'>
```

Which, of course is true, but I don't see how it's relevant, because a *DataFile* has one (and only one) *LogOutput* which, in turn, belongs to only this one *DataFile*.

I read [Question 1744203](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744203/django-admin-onetoone-relation-as-an-inline) but the solution there was to reverse the direction of the relationship. I don't think I can do that because other objects (*Suites*) also have *LogOutputs*.

And, if it matters, this is in Django 1.5.

My question is: What do I need to do in order to display the inline *LogOutput* on the *DataFile's* admin page? (Or is my thinking about the use of a OneToOneField in need of revision?)

TIA!

Comment: Have you tried the fk_name?
fk_name = "logoutput"

Comment: I am unfamiliar with it. I'll have a look.

Comment: It appears to be the same problem. Specifically that the directionality is still presumed to be the other way: LogOutputInline.fk_name' refers to field '<class 'trial.models.DataFile'>' that is missing from model 'trial.LogOutput

Comment: Seems its correct behavior: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18059

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django Admin: OneToOne Relation as an Inline?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744203/django-admin-onetoone-relation-as-an-inline)

Comment: @Anto - The question itself already refers to [Django Admin: OneToOne Relation as an Inline?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744203/django-admin-onetoone-relation-as-an-inline) as a possible duplicate AND why it's NOT applicable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The internal ORM and admin are pretty smart, but where OOP runs up against table structure, things can be a bit imprecise.  I'd recommend giving the ORM a little hint by using an [abstract base class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) like this:

```
class LogOutput(models.Model):
    raw = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class DataFileLogOutput(LogOutput):
    pass

class SuiteFileLogOutput(LogOutput):
    pass

class DataFile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()#etc.
    logoutput = models.OneToOneField(DataFileLogOutput)

class Suite(models.Model):
    # Many Suites will have the same datafile:
    datafile = models.ForeignKey(DataFile)

    # Each Suite has a unique LogOutput different from the DataFile's
    # and as with the DataFile, that LogOutput will have just one Suite
    logoutput = models.OneToOneField(SuiteLogOutput)
```

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping to avoid that, but I can see how my mental model of it might not line up with how the ORM manages the SQL.  Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: How does this allow the reversing of the logoutput OneToOne relation in the admin? (regarding the directionality of how admin resolves relations)

Comment: This is not possible when havong auth.User (django's system user) as Model. I can't change that (without much hassle).

Answer (score 5):

There's also a django add-on to get inlining without having to reverse the direction of the OneToOneField(s): [django_reverse_admin](https://github.com/anziem/django_reverse_admin/)

You'll need to add django_reverse_admin to your requirements.txt:

```
-e git+https://github.com/anziem/django_reverse_admin.git#egg=django_reverse_admin
```

Then import it:

admin.py

```
from django_reverse_admin import ReverseModelAdmin

# don't need to define an inline for LogOutput

class DataFileAdmin(ReverseModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['name']
    inline_reverse = ['logoutput']
    inline_type = 'tabular'  # or could be 'stacked'

admin.site.register(DataFile, DataFileAdmin)
```