# How can I prevent the fields in inlines to reference the latest created object in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a model `PlacedOrder` that is referenced by other models using  `OneToOneField` and `ForeignKey`. So I am using `StackedTabularInline` to render it on my `PlacedOrderAdmin` model.

The weird behavior is that when I start my django application I can create a new `PlacedOrder` object with no problems but after that when I try to create another object the fields on the inlines are already filled with the content from the object that I just created and I can't create a new object no matter what I try, it keeps showing me the error "Please correct the errors below."

Only the fields that belongs to the inlines does that, the fields from the model `PlacedOrder` are "clean". If I restart django I can see all the objects created and their data seems correct.

part of the Models:

```py
class PlacedOrder(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4(),
        editable=False
    )
    ...
    total = models.DecimalField(
        _('total'),
        max_digits=8,
        decimal_places=2
    )


class OrderStatus(models.Model):
    placed_order = models.OneToOneField(
        PlacedOrder,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    status = models.CharField(
        _('status'),
        choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
        max_length=30,
    )
```

Here is one of the inlines:

```py
class OrderStatusInline(nested_admin.NestedTabularInline):
    model = app_models.OrderStatus
```

and the Order

```py
@admin.register(app_models.PlacedOrder)
class OrderAdmin(nested_admin.NestedModelAdmin):
    inlines = (OrderStatusInline, OrderPaymentInline, OrderDeliveryInline, SelectedProductInline, )
```

## **Fixed it**

So I found out that the problem had nothing to do with what I posted here, it was actually how I was declaring the `id` inside `PlacedOrder`.

On my original model I had the default set as `uuid.uuid4()` but that was creating all the problem, once I changed it to `uuid.uuid4` everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that with a `OneToOne` relationship the actual field defining the relationship has to be on the inline model, not the parent one - in just the same way as for a ForeignKey

Take a look at this post for more info: [Django Admin: OneToOne Relation as an Inline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744203/django-admin-onetoone-relation-as-an-inline)

Comment: But that is how it is right now. The `PlacedOrder` is the parent one and `OrderStatus` which has the `OneToOne` is referenced inside the `OrderStatusInline`. I will double check but I'm almost sure that all the inlines are already like that.