# How can I inline a Form of a OneToOne Relation

Tags: django, django-forms

I have the following django models where a OneToOne Relation is used.

Models:

```
class ClientCustomFields(models.Model):
    some_custom_id = models.CharField(max_length=36, blank=True, null=True)
    # .... more custom fields


class Client(ExternalIdModel):
    first_name = CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = CharField(max_length=200)
```

Now, since this is an easy 1:1 relation, I want to embed the form of the custom fields directly into the form of the customer. But I am having troubles stitching the Forms together.

```
class ClientCustomFieldsForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ClientCustomFields
        fields = '__all__'


class ClientForm(ModelForm):
    custom_fields = ClientCustomFieldsForm()

    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = '__all__'
```

I have tried a couple of others like `BaseInlineFormSet` but without any luck so far.

Although there is a similar question [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744203/django-admin-onetoone-relation-as-an-inline), this however, is admin related and at least I could not figure out how this could help me.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve by combining the forms together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to display one form to create objects for two models. This can be achieved using a [django-betterforms](https://django-betterforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/multiform.html) class called `MultiModelForm`. After having created your two ModelForms, combine them :

```py
# forms.py

from betterforms.multiform import MultiModelForm

class MyMultiForm(MultiModelForm):
    form_classes = {"client": ClientForm, "client_custom": ClientCustomFieldsForm}
```

Then adapt your view to call this multiform :

```py
# views.py

from django.views.generic import CreateView
from .forms import MyMultiForm

class MyFormView(CreateView) :
    form_class = MyMultiForm
    ...
```

Using a multiform, you can access each of your ModelForms fields with a dictionary syntax, using the keys you chose when you created the MultiModelForm : for example, in your view, `form['client'].first_name`, and in your template, `{{ form.client.first_name }}`

Only thing left to do is to *actually* create your two objects when the form has been filled. Something like this :

```py
class MyFormView(CreateView) :
    form_class = MyMultiForm

    def form_valid(self, form) :
        client = Client(
            first_name = forms["client"].cleaned_data["first_name"]
            last_name = forms["client"].cleaned_data["last_name"]
        )
        client.save()

        client_custom = ClientCustomFields(
            some_custom_id = forms["client_custom"].cleaned_data["some_custom_id"]
            ...
        )
        client_custom.save()

        return redirect(self.get_success_url())
```

And there you go ! Hope this helps !